# How to write Internationalization out put message in eclipse console in java

Tags: internationalization

I have written a core java internationalization program but in eclipse console I am not able to see the out put message. The reason is its not ASCII code.  I changed the console preferences to UTF-8 then also not able to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is Windows-only and believe it or not, it is not related to console encoding. It is related to source file encoding.
In the Project Explorer (or Package Explorer, it doesn't matter) right-click on a source file and choose Properties. Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a selected source file to activate the same dialog.

In the Properties dialog make sure that Resource tab is selected and at the bottom of this tab switch text file encoding to UTF-8 (by default it will be Windows-family encoding...).

Run the program again and that should do the trick.
Each file that does any printing must be encoded like that. Don't ask me why, I guess it has something to do with Eclipse long history of weirdness.

Comment: your solution is not working. Please provide other suggestions.

Comment: @Satish: Of course I can help you, but first you'll need to help yourself. Can you edit the question, put the code you use to display messages, as well as messages themselves? A screenshot from the output would also be great idea. Judging by your (nick?) name, it might be the case of unsupported font...